# Android appcompat v7 support library Notification compact view repeating buttons issue

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-appcompat

This is the method I use to retrieve/create/update app's notification inside a service class, called PlayerService:

```
    import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;

    // ...
        private Notification getCompatNotification(String contentText) {
                m_notificationBuilder
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("PlayerService")
                        .setContentText(contentText)
                        .setContentIntent(null)
                        .setWhen(0)
                        .setShowWhen(false)
                        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "", null)
                        .addAction((isPlaying() ? android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause : android.R.drawable.ic_media_play), "", null)
                        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "", null)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()                                    
                                .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2)
                                .setShowCancelButton(true)
                                .setCancelButtonIntent(null))
                        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

                Notification notification = m_notificationBuilder.build();

                return notification;
            }
```

Now, when the media player activity is opened but playback not started, notification shows its big view with those 3 action buttons(previous, play/pause, next), but when the playback is started, notification view changes to compact and displays those 3 buttons in first place and then again the first and second. Please see the images.
Test device has KitKat 4.4.4.

No Playback
[image]

Playback started
[image]

To update notification:

```
private void updateNotification(String contentText){
                nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getCompatNotification(contentText));
}
```

And in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        m_notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
}
```

In `onStartCommand()`:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getCompatNotification("Test Content"));
        return START_STICKY; // run until explicitly stopped.
    }
```

Can't figure out what is the problem. Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same *NotificationCompat.Builder* instance to create your Notifications and whenever you add an *Action* it is added to the previous *List* and creates an unwanted behavior into the System Api. You have to call *clearActions()* first on the Builder before adding any if you want to use the same Builder instance.

Comment: Your answer makes a very good point, but there is no such method as clearActions() for NotificationCompat.Builder. Aside from that, can't understand why is this not specified anywhere? Isn't it a good practice to use the same builder object for create/update operations?

Comment: Ok, so it looks like there's a request to add these methods(clearActions and removeAction) - [Issue 207040]:(https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207040).  For now, I can use `m_notificationBuilder.mActions.clear();`    @mariusc thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

hope this could help: add `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` to your button

Comment: my buttons are created by the addActions() method of the notificationBuilder object, it's not a custom layout, it is the v7 library support which allows building notification with MediaStyle style.